# Display paragraph text after 5 rows

Tags: php

am new to programming.
Am trying to display a text after 5 rows from the database.
thanks in advance

example:

```
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>

<p>Hello World</p>

 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>

<p>Hello World</p>

 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
 <row></row>
```

my php query:

```
$post_status= "Published";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_post WHERE status = ? GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY post_id DESC");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $post_status);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //display the outcome here
        }
      }

else {
  echo "No User Post";
}
```

The php code works well i just thought of what if i want to show an image or a text after about 5 rows. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post_status= "Published";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_post WHERE status = ? GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY post_id DESC");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $post_status);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$counter = 1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<row>Your row</row>'
        if ($counter % 5 == 0) {
           echo '<p>Your paragprah</p>';
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}

else {
  echo "No User Post";
}
```